# Exclude package(s) from custom module

Tags: maven

I have a one module (i.e common module) in this there were multiple packages. I am going to inject common module into another project. I wanted to include/exclude some packages from common module as other project will going to use only few packages from common module. is there any way or maven plugin to exclude packages from module ?

```
    |--common-module 
       |-- com.parser
          |--jsonParser.java
          |--xyz.java
       |-- com.http
          |--RestTemplet.java
```

> Project1 --> include common-module but it should exclude com.parser package

> Project2 --> include common-module but it should exclude com.http package

Any input would be highly appreciated

Comment: Make separate modules... the cleanest solution.

Comment: But in that case I will have to maintain multiple modules, let's say what if there will be 100 small module ? It will indirectly increase code maintainability.

Comment: So what? You have to maintain the code either ... so where is the real problem? So you have 100 small modules? What is the real problem? If you have more small module you can increase the parallelization via `mvn -T .. ` and in consequence increase building speed...

Comment: The problem here is maintainability, instead one common module having different level of package I thought it would be easy to maintain further.

Comment: You seemed to be mixing packages with modules. If you try to break of the convention over configuration (CoC) in Maven (which you can do but I strongly recommend not to do it) it will produce much more problems related to maintainability in contradiction to have more modules which follow the convention over configuration paradigm(CoC). I have maintained builds with ca. 800+ modules and the biggest issue was that people had started to create modules which didn't follow CoC not the number of modules was the problem.

Comment: It's also a clear separation of concern on the module level which you would follow...in Classes/Packages you usually do it as well to clean parts here...the same on module level ... Not a module which contains two separate packages which do not belong together ...

Answer (score 1):

Modules are the smallest unit.

Either you include a module as dependency or you don't.

Comment: You mean excluding classes or packages in not possible within <dependency> tags in POM, is it ? 
and is there any performance impacts between segregation of multiple module based on certain criteria or one single module and use across project1 and project2 (based on my question above)

Comment: A dependency is related 1-to-1 to a jar file which means in consequence the jar file will be there or it is not there (given dependency or not given). On a dependency you can not exclude classes as you can't do that on java command line...